# Resuming all threads in waiting state using notify method only

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I want to resume all the threads which goes into waiting state using notify method only. **I don't want to use notifyAll() to resume all the threads in waiting state.**

```
public class MultithreadingTest{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws  Exception{
        SharedResource sr = new SharedResource();
        sr.isWaiting = true; // to make thread to go in waiting state
        Thread t1 = new Thread(sr);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(sr);
        Thread t3 = new Thread(sr);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        sr.isWaiting = false; // to directly call the notify() based on condition
        Thread t6 = new Thread(sr);
        t6.start();
    }
}

class SharedResource implements Runnable{
    volatile boolean isWaiting;
    public void run(){
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " enters with status " + this.isWaiting);
        synchronized (this){
            try {
                if(this.isWaiting) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " goes into waiting stage");
                    wait(); // Release the lock so other threads can acquire it
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " wakes up");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " calling the notify method");
                }
                notify(); // Notifying the random thread which is in waiting state to resume again
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Calling wait() will release the intrinsic lock so that other threads in queue can acquire it. I want the last thread to directly call the notify() which will notify any of the threads which is in waiting state to resume again. Waiting thread wakes up and call the notify() which will again resume the thread in waiting state.

Comment: Why have you synchronized code in the ```run``` method?

Comment: To call wait or notify on any object we must have to acquire lock on it using synchronized. Directly calling wait or notify will throw IllegalMonitorStateException. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Why don't you want to call `notifyAll()`? It's recommended to use that instead of `notify()`.

Comment: @Kayaman I am trying to learn thread lifecycle in deep. I just want to know is it possible to resume all the threads without using notifyAll(). I am not planning to use it in any real world scenario.

Comment: note that the code contains a race- after thread t1 is started, there is *no guarantee* that thread t1 will enter the `synchronized` block, and go into waiting state, **before** the main thread sets the isWaiting variable to false.

Comment: if the main thread sets the `isWaiting` variable before threads t1, t2, and t3 are put to sleep, then your code can not behave as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, we want for these actions to happen in order:

- spawn thread T1, T2 and T3, and put all three to sleep on the shared-resource
- change the volatile flag, and spawn T4
- T4 enters the critical section, wakes one sleeping thread, and then exits
- after being notified, each thread notifies exactly one time and then exits

The code above is almost correct, but since the `main` method is executed by the "main" thread, we must ensure that threads T1,T2,T3 go in the waiting state **before** spawning thread T4. We can do that by using a semaphore. The `main` thread will block on the `semaphore.acquire()` call, until all threads are in the right state.

**Note** that due to a race, in the code above thread T1 could enter the critical section **after** the flag is set to false- so we'd lose control of the actions order.

See the update code below, it will output something like

```
main thread starts
Thread-2 enters with status true
Thread-2 goes into waiting stage
Thread-1 enters with status true
Thread-1 goes into waiting stage
Thread-0 enters with status true
Thread-0 goes into waiting stage
Thread-3 enters with status false
Thread-3 calling the notify method
Thread-3 terminates
main thread terminates
Thread-2 wakes up
Thread-2 terminates
Thread-1 wakes up
Thread-1 terminates
Thread-0 wakes up
Thread-0 terminates
```

---

**The code**

```
package sample;

import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class MultithreadingTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("main thread starts");
    SharedResource sr = new SharedResource();
    // to make thread to go in waiting state
    sr.isWaiting = true;
    Thread t1 = new Thread(sr);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(sr);
    Thread t3 = new Thread(sr);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();

    // let the main thread wait, until all 3 threads reach the checkpoint
    sr.numWaiting.acquire(3);
    sr.isWaiting = false; // to directly call the notify() based on condition
    Thread t6 = new Thread(sr);
    t6.start();
    System.out.println("main thread terminates");
  }
}

class SharedResource implements Runnable {
  // keep a count of how many threads entered the critical section
  // needed by the main thread to know when to start the "wake-up" thread
  Semaphore numWaiting = new Semaphore(0);
  volatile boolean isWaiting;

  public void run() {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " enters with status " + this.isWaiting);
    synchronized (this) {
      try {
        if (this.isWaiting) {
          System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " goes into waiting stage");
          numWaiting.release(1);
          wait(); // Release the lock so other threads can acquire it
          System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " wakes up");
        } else {
          System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " calling the notify method");
        }
        notify(); // Notifying the random thread which is in waiting state to resume again
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " terminates");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As a alternative approach I am making main thread to sleep and then calling the last spawn thread. It is working fine. But If I try to call the join() on T1, T2 and T3 before starting the last spawn thread T4 they all went to wait state but then T4 is not getting called to notify them

Comment: if you call join() on T1 in the main method, before starting thread T4, then you end with all threads blocked. The main thread will block on the join() call, until the T1 thread terminates. But T1 is waiting, so it can't terminate. And since thread main is paused, thread T4 is never started-